# How to make a web component redraw when its DOM is modified?

Tags: html, plot, canvas, charts, web-component

I have [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/rodde-radial-pie-chart.js) for rendering radial pie charts in HTML documents. It works fine, yet it does not update when I modify the DOM which "marks" the chart.

The code that fails:

```
<script>
    function modify() {
        const chart = document.getElementsByTagName("radial-pie-chart")[1];
        var entry = document.createElement("entry");
        entry.setAttribute("color", "orange");
        entry.setAttribute("value", 70);
        chart.appendChild(entry);
        console.log("hello");
    }
            
    setTimeout(modify, 2000);
</script>
```

Q: How could I repeat rendering upon DOM changes? I guess I need some callback to that end?

Comment: Web Components can respond to **attribute** changes defined in the Web Components ``observedAttributes`` array. If you want to monitor DOM **node** changes you need to use the standard MutationObserver API. FYI, I did a 999 Bytes ``<pie-chart>`` in https://pie-meister.github.io

Comment: Note, it is more common to add a ``.addValue`` **method** to your ``<pie-chart>`` Web Component. Calling that **method** does not require the Mutation Observer API.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Could you provide an answer? That would be a nice one.

Comment: Nah, you can write your solution with your own code. After 2 days or so StackOverflow allows you to mark your own answer as correct